# How to read a table using tabindex table value along with header

Tags: html, tabindex

I have a table using html

**Name | Place**

Asha | Hyderabad

Neelima | Bangalore

So the reader should read in such a way that Name Asha Place Hyderabad Name Neelima Place Bangalore

I can able to read row like 
Name Place Asha Hyderabad Neelima Bangalore 
which is not correct format to read.

```
<table class="table-base">
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" tabindex="0">Name></th>
       <th scope="col" tabindex="0">Place</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
   <tr>
     <td tabindex="0">Asha</td>
     </td tabindex=0>Hyderabad</td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>Asha</td>
     </td>Bangalore</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if this is what you need, but if you need a vertical table you can use the following HTML format.

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: left;
}
/*Separates the rows belonging to different items*/
tr:nth-child(2n):not(:last-child) { /*change this depending on the amount of rows per item i.e. 3 rows -> 3n */
  border-bottom: 3px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table class="table-base">
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Asha</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Place</th>
    <td>Hyderabad</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>Neelima</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Place</th>
    <td>Bangalore</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```